# Cordova CLI on OSX

Tags: macos, cordova, cordova-cli

When I am trying to build the iOS version of our app on OSX (10.9), I am getting the following error. I have updated, uninstalled and reinstalled cordova with no success.

I have also looked for the error to see if anyone has come across it before with no luck. Does anyone have any idea at what could be causing the issue?

```
$ cordova build ios
Error: Unencoded <
Line: 0
Column: 2
Char: <
    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:347:8)
    at strictFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:364:22)
    at Object.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:671:11)
    at XMLParser.feed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
    at ElementTree.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:263:10)
    at Object.exports.XML (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:593:13)
    at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/util/xml-helpers.js:126:38)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:88:31
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.handlePrepare (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/prepare.js:81:24)
```

Comment: A silly question of mine, but it will help to have some background info, Did you already created a project using the cordova CLI commands and added the iOS platform? Also, what you get form running "which cordova"?

Comment: The project is not new, it has worked on iOS in the past. Cordova is in "/user/local/bin/cordova". I haven't removed and re-added the ios platform yet but I think that is the next step.

Comment: Yes, sometimes removing and adding the platform again solves some problems i have faced when doing updates.

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using? you could run `cordova -v` to test that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error triggered by broken `plugin.xml` file for one of the plugins which you are using. Make sure that all such files are valid XML documents. Such files could be found in the `plugins` folder of your Cordova project root.